# Spark SQL - How to select on dates stored as UTC millis from the epoch?

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been searching and have not found a solution as to how one might query on dates stored as UTC milliseconds from the epoch using Spark SQL.  The schema I have pulled in from a NoSQL datasource (JSON from MongoDB) has the target date as:

```
|-- dateCreated: struct (nullable = true)

||-- $date: long (nullable = true)
```

The complete schema is as follows:

```
scala> accEvt.printSchema
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- appId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- expires: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- $date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- another key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- class: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- flavors: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- foo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- test: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- testKey: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- testKey2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateCreated: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- originationDate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- processedDate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- receivedDate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $date: long (nullable = true)
```

and my goal is to write queries along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE dateCreated BETWEEN [dateStoredAsLong0] AND [dateStoredAsLong1]
```

My process thus far has been:

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@29200d25

scala> val accEvt = sqlContext.jsonFile("/home/bkarels/mongoexport/accomplishment_event.json")

...
14/10/29 15:03:38 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: reduce at JsonRDD.scala:46, took 4.668981083 s
accEvt: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD = 
SchemaRDD[6] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:103

scala> accEvt.registerAsTable("accomplishmentEvent")
```

*(At this point the following base line query executes successfully)*

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from accomplishmentEvent").collect.foreach(println)
...
[74475]
```

Now, the voodoo that I cannot get right is how to form my select statement to reason about the dates.  For example the following executes w/o error, but returns zero rather than the count of all records as it should (74475).

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from accomplishmentEvent where processedDate >= '1970-01-01'").collect.foreach(println)
...
[0]
```

I have also tried some ugliness like:

```
scala> val now = new java.util.Date()
now: java.util.Date = Wed Oct 29 15:05:15 CDT 2014

scala> val today = now.getTime
today: Long = 1414613115743

scala> val thirtydaysago = today - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
thirtydaysago: Long = 1416316083039


scala> sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from accomplishmentEvent where processedDate <= %s and processedDate >= %s".format(today,thirtydaysago)).collect.foreach(println)
```

As recommended, I've selected on a named field to ensure that works.  So:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select receivedDate from accomplishmentEvent limit 10").collect.foreach(println)
```

returns:

```
[[1376318850033]]
[[1376319429590]]
[[1376320804289]]
[[1376320832835]]
[[1376320832960]]
[[1376320835554]]
[[1376320914480]]
[[1376321041899]]
[[1376321109341]]
[[1376321121469]]
```

Then extending to try and get some kind of dates working I have tried:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select cId from accomplishmentEvent where receivedDate.date > '1970-01-01' limit 5").collect.foreach(println)
```

Results in the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No such field date in StructType(ArrayBuffer(StructField($date,LongType,true)))
...
```

Prefixing our field name with `$` as also suggested results in a different kind of error:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select cId from accomplishmentEvent where receivedDate.$date > '1970-01-01' limit 5").collect.foreach(println)
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.69] failure: ``UNION'' expected but ErrorToken(illegal character) found

select actualConsumerId from accomplishmentEvent where receivedDate.$date > '1970-01-01' limit 5
```

Clearly I am not getting how to select on dates stored in this way - can anyone help me fill in this gap?

I am newer to both Scala and Spark, so forgive me if this is an elementary question, but my searches have turned up empty on the forums and Spark documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify which aspect you're having trouble with? Is it constructing the right filter expression (i.e.: WHERE clause) in your query? Also, presumably you've figured out how to get your data into an `RDD`: what is the `RDD`'s type?

Comment: I have added a great deal more detail to my post outlining more precisely what I have done and what it is that is evading me.  Thank you.

Comment: Two things to try: (1) add the full output of accEvt.printSchema() to your question (or is the snippet at the top actually the whole thing?) and (2) try selecting a specific field (or fields) rather than * to check that your field naming is working. It looks like your JSON isn't flat so I wonder if perhaps the field shown in your snippet needs to be addressed as dataCreated.$data -- and I observe that the JSON example in the Spark SQL documentation **is** flat.

Comment: I've verified that in Spark 1.1.0 the dot notation works for accessing nested fields. However, your next problem will be that your field name has a "$" in it, and `dateCreated.$date` is not a valid Spark SQL identifier. It seems related to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2775) which really should have been written to say something more general. The usual SQL square bracket quoting doesn't work either. The Spark SQL parser is really quite primitive and likely to be rewritten soon. Maybe you can process the RDD to get rid of the dollar sign, or pre-process the file.

Comment: Just noticed your most recent edit. Notice how your `receivedDate` is printed out with **two** square brackets? That's the nesting in action!

Comment: Yes, I have successfully queried for other nested fields but this one does behave differently as you have stated.  Looks like I need to keep digging to find a work around and see if something crafty can be done.  Thank you for all of your feedback and suggestions!  I will post a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not flat, so the fields below the top level need to be addressed using qualified names, such as `dateCreated.$date`. Your specific date fields are all of `long` type, so you'll need to do numerical comparisons on them and it looks like you were on the right track for doing those.

An additional problem is that your field names have "$" characters, and Spark SQL won't let you query on them. One solution is that instead of reading the JSON directly as a `SchemaRDD` (as you have done) you first read it as an `RDD[String]`, use the `map` method to perform the Scala string manipulations of your choice, and then use `SQLContext`'s `jsonRDD` method to create the `SchemaRDD`.

```
val lines = sc.textFile(...)
// you may want something less naive than global replacement of all "$" chars
val linesFixed = lines.map(s => s.replaceAllLiterally("$", ""))
val accEvt = sqlContext.jsonRDD(linesFixed)
```

I've tested this with Spark 1.1.0.

For reference, the lack of quoting capability in Spark SQL has been noted in [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2775) and perhaps others, and it seems that the fix was recently [checked in](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/974d7b238b415791975c60e4e202265d6fd31e2d), but will take some time to make it into a release

Comment: So for some reason the mongo export in the original JSON converted my date objects to have that nested $date field name.  So I test drove your idea and converted '$date' -> 'date' and then I could query against the long values using, for example `"select processedDate.date"`.  I still have to convert dates to millis and inject them into the queries to do ranges and what not, but I suppose that is the price you pay for storing dates in that way.  I will now have to look into what mongo export is doing and build that into our strategy moving forward.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that you can do other translations during your pass through the data. Converting the epoch milliseconds to some other Scala date format (lots of info in questions/answers on this site) is quite easy. The problem is you'll need to figure out what kind of date comparison Spark SQL can actually handle (which I haven't looked into). OTOH, it's also pretty straight forward to filter an RDD using straight Spark if it turns out that Spark SQL can't [yet] handle what you want.